# Does Android SDK work in Solaris?

Tags: solaris, android

I want to compile my Android app in a Solaris server. Though, from [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) all I can see are Windows/MacOS/Linux versions. Does anyone know if I can install and use the Linux binaries in a Solaris machine? If not, are there alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there exist tools to make linux binaries run on Solaris you won't be able to use the Android SDK binaries on Solaris, except java based ones. If the Android SDK is open source you could of course compile it on solaris, however I was unable to determine if it is open source.

The alternative would be to set up a linux (virtual) machine. My distribution of choice would be Debian stable (which is what I use for Android development).

Comment: (Some versions of) Solaris can execute some Linux executables (for the same processor architectures) through a compatibility layer. The Android SDK is open source. In principle it could be ported to Solaris, but I doubt anyone cares to spend the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Your going to need gnu make 1.8 I believe its very specific to that. You may also need GCC Gnu not Unix C Compiler. If you can get those and Sun-java6-sdk running on Unix, let us all know. Python 2.6-7, build-essential, a lot of other stuff to that you may not be able the get the source for like sun-java. Though I have heard of some successes with CM and Open-java-sdk . Its hard to imagine sun wouldn't have a Unix binary.

More I think about it. Why the hell did they leave gnu n GPL (ie glibc) if its all the foundation for building android?

Comment: Solaris includes Java out of the box.  (They were both Sun products, now both Oracle products.)  Python, gcc, & gmake are included in later Solaris releases as well.  None of that is specific to the Android SDK.